# What is wrong with my Minimax code in CS50-Tictactoe?

Tags: python, cs50

The rest of functions like actions(board) or result(board, action), are good and working effectively, basedes my Minimax() method works perfectly when I choose "O" as player, but when choose "X" AI Minimax System turns too much weird:
*sorry for the basic english but im chilean (from LA)
Here is my code:

```
def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    # Defining AI
    current_player = player(board)
    # Randomizing first move
    if board == initial_state():
        a = random.randint(0, 2)
        b = random.randint(0, 2)
        return [a, b]

    # if the game is ended none action is valid
    if terminal(board):
        return None

    # Storing all possible actions
    Actions = actions(board)

    # If one action returns a terminal board then realize that
    for action in Actions:
         if terminal(result(board, action)):
             return action

    # Randomizing first move
    if board == initial_state():
        a = random.randint(0, 2)
        b = random.randint(0, 2)
        return [a, b]

    # X maximize the utility
    if current_player == X:
        v = -math.inf
        for action in Actions:
            k = min_value(result(board, action))
            if k > v:
                v = k
                move = action

    # O minimize the utility
    if current_player == O:
        v = math.inf
        for action in Actions:
            k = max_value(result(board, action))
            if k < v:
                v = k
                move= action

    return move


def max_value(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    v = -math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = max(v, min_value(result(board, action)))
    return v


def min_value(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return utility(board)
    v = math.inf
    for action in actions(board):
        v = min(v, max_value(result(board, action)))
    return v
```

Comment: Your English seems fine, but if you get tired of writing questions in English, there is always this: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That said, you're going to have to be more specific as to what your problem is, other than "it's just weird." See [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help